# Isometries from Diffeomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Given a compact, connected Lie group G of diffeomorphisms on a manifold M, how to construct a Riemannian metric on M such that elements of G are isometries of M?

Comment: Fix any Riemann metric on $M$ and average it over the action of $G$.

Comment: I need compactness for the Haar measure. But can't I do without connectedness?

Comment: Connectedness is irrelevant. A compact Lie group has a Haar measure. Just average any Riemann metric over $G$ wrt that measure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible without connectedness. You need the fact that the connected component of a Lie Group G that contains the identity of G is a closed, connected normal subgroup of G.